# Step through assembly language functions in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, masm

I'm trying to step through an assembly function in Visual Studio 2010, but whenever the debugger reaches the `ret` statement, a window is displayed with the text "no source available", and then the debugger simply exits the program. Is it even possible to run x86 assembly language programs in the Visual Studio debugger when they contain function calls?

```
.686p
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 2048
.data
ExitProcess proto, exitcode:dword
.code

start:

jumpIfEqual PROC var1:DWORD, var2:DWORD, jmpAddress:DWORD
    mov eax,var1
    cmp eax,var2
    jne skip
    pop eax
    push jmpAddress
    skip:
    ret ;this statement opens up a window in Visual Studio with the text "no source available", and then the program simply exits
jumpIfEqual ENDP

push OFFSET jumpIfEqual ;call the function
mov eax, 5 ;set the parameters for the function
push eax
push eax
call jumpIfEqual

invoke  ExitProcess, 0
end start
```

Comment: What is calling the assembly function?

Comment: See above: `push OFFSET jumpIfEqual ;call the function`

Comment: Your entire program is written in assembly language?  How do you get output?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not trying to produce any console output: I'm just trying to get assembly language functions to work correctly in the Visual Studio 2010 debugger.

Comment: Just trying to get my mind around this.  Where is the entry point for the program?  The `start` label?  If so, `ret` will return to the operating system.  Also, I don't get the `push OFFSET`.  Making a `call` will automatically push the address of the next instruction onto the stack, call the sub, and then pop the pushed address into the Program Counter when `ret` is executed.

Comment: Alright.  Well, I think you should try [this detailed tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/271627/Assembly-Programming-with-Visual-Studio-2010-2012).